# Populating Mail Item with texts and Images

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have the following code in Excel VBA:

```
Sub CreateEmailAndSend()

    Dim outApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oMail = outApp.CreateItem(0)
    Dim Doc As Object

    oMail.Display
    Set Doc = outApp.ActiveInspector.WordEditor

    oMail.To = ""
    oMail.Subject = "test"

    ' first sentence
    Dim msg As String
    msg = "Plain Sentence"

    Doc.Range(0, 0) = msg

    ' second sentence comes after
    msg = "Bold and Highlight Yellow Sentence"
    Doc.Range(Len(Doc.Range), Len(Doc.Range)) = msg
    Doc.Range.Font.Bold = True
    Doc.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

    ' paste image below it
    Dim imagerng As Range
    Set imagerng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 5))
    imagerng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap

    Doc.Range(Len(Doc.Range), Len(Doc.Range)).Paste

End Sub
```

Basically what I would like to do is to create and display an email that looks like this:

> Plain Sentence
>   Bold and Highlight Yellow Sentence (this sentence is bold and highlighted)
>   (bitmap image)
>   {my signature}

However, the output I got from my code is

> Plain Sentence (bold)
>   (bitmap image) and the second sentence all over {my signature}

How should I fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the way you are trying to access Ranges in the Word object model. After some googling I have replaced your `Doc.Range(Len(Doc.Range), Len(Doc.Range)).` sections with paragraph references. See below:

```
Sub CreateEmailAndSend()

    Dim outApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oMail = outApp.CreateItem(0)
    Dim Doc As Object

    oMail.Display
    Set Doc = outApp.ActiveInspector.WordEditor

    oMail.To = ""
    oMail.Subject = "test"

    ' first sentence
    Dim msg As String
    msg = "Plain Sentence"

    Doc.Range(0, 0) = msg

    ' second sentence comes after
    msg = "Bold and Highlight Yellow Sentence"

    Doc.Paragraphs(1).Range.InsertParagraphAfter
    Doc.Paragraphs(2).Range = msg
    Doc.Paragraphs(2).Range.Font.Bold = True
    Doc.Paragraphs(2).Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow


    ' paste image below it
    Dim imagerng As Range
    Set imagerng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 5))
    imagerng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap

    Doc.Paragraphs(2).Range.InsertParagraphAfter
    Doc.Paragraphs(3).Range.InsertParagraphAfter
    Doc.Paragraphs(3).Range.Paste

End Sub
```

This is now working for me.

Comment: Seems like the yellow highlight doesn't work on my end. Any ideas why?

Comment: It wasn't on mine either, I had hoped it was something to do with my environment. However, I now have it working by changing wdYellow for the explicit value which is 7.